# Register new Client ID on Instagram Developers Page

Tags: android, ios, iphone, instagram, instagram-api

I am unable to register new Client ID on Instagram developers page. Everytime I got error The captcha solution was not correct. Please try again. I am trying more than one day.

Comment: What says instagram support? Write them first.

Comment: @Miller Can you tell me how I can contact with instagram support team.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/developer/support/

Comment: Do one thing delete your previous added dummy client id and try to add new.

Comment: @Miller, I am trying it what can not find how I can contact to instagram support team using this.

Comment: @user459460 Now I am only able to create account not able to create client Id.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the CSP , i solve the problem using a CSP Disabler Extension, At the momment you disactivated it , the recapcha will be show. It work for me like 3 hours ago , From a Mac and using Google Chrome. I hope this helps.

I won't post the Extesion that i used because they deleted my last answer and telling me it was a "Drive-by-link-dropping". I reposting the answer only to try to help the OP.